# Using IN (SELECT ....) as a condition

Tags: sql

I'm having an error with the simplified SQL code below and I need your help to resolve it.

```
SELECT user

FROM Table1      

WHERE

user = IF( CURRENT_USER() in (select name from Table2) , user, CURRENT_USER() )
```

The function CURRENT_USER() returns the name of the user who enters the dashboard I'm creating.

So basically, I would like to return a list of user names from Table1 if the current user is listed in the name column of Table2. If not listed, only current user's name will be returned.

I get this error:

**Semijoin expression (i.e. "x IN (SELECT ...)") must be a part of logical AND.**

I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Dremel

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly

```
SELECT user
FROM Table1      
WHERE CURRENT_USER() in (select name from Table2) 
   OR user = CURRENT_USER()
```

This will return all the rows from `Table1` when `CURRENT_USER()` is present in `Table2`.

In case if you want to restrict the data from `Table1` when `CURRENT_USER()` is present in `Table2` then

```
SELECT user
FROM Table1      
WHERE (CURRENT_USER() in (select name from Table2) and some_col = 'some_condition')
   OR user = CURRENT_USER()
```

**Update :**

Try this syntax

```
SELECT user
FROM Table1      
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from Table2 where name = CURRENT_USER()) 
   OR user = CURRENT_USER()
```

Comment: getting this error now "-Expecting [EOF], but found 'OR'"

Comment: All these are Native SQL queries. Now am out of options. May be `USER`  is a reserved keyword

Comment: USER is an example term, I use something different in my own code but thanks for your suggestions !